# White-space: pre is causing horizontal scroll, white-space: pre-wrap is causing shrinking. How to combine usage of both?

Tags: html, css

I have table and row of elements and I need to display tooltip on hover. Cell element's size is fixed, but hovering element is wider and has multiple lines. Problem is that using "white-space: pre", makes it work as intended when there is a space, but not when hovering is happening close to right side of the container, causing horizontal scroll, at the same time setting "white-space: pre-wrap" is causing text shrinking when it has space and should be wider, but act as intended when there is no space.

How can I make hovered text be fully expanded when there is available space, but shrinked when there isn't, like being close to the right side of container ??

```css
.container {
/* only to limit redundant code and simulate approaching to right edge of screen*/
    width: 400px;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.tooltip::after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: blue;
    display: none;
    white-space: pre;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.tooltip:hover::after {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table class="tab">
        <td class=" tooltip" data-title="Lorem Ipsum
      Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum aaa
      Lorem Ipsum"><button>btn</button></td>
        <td class=" tooltip" data-title="Lorem Ipsum
      Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum aaa
      Lorem Ipsum"><button>btn</button></td>
        <td class=" tooltip" data-title="Lorem Ipsum
      Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum aaa
      Lorem Ipsum"><button>btn</button></td>
        <td class=" tooltip" data-title="Lorem Ipsum
      Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum aaa
      Lorem Ipsum"><button>btn</button></td>
        <td class=" tooltip" data-title="Lorem Ipsum
      Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum aaa
      Lorem Ipsum"><button>btn</button></td>
        <td class=" tooltip" data-title="Lorem Ipsum
      Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum aaa
      Lorem Ipsum"><button>btn</button></td>
        <td class=" tooltip" data-title="Lorem Ipsum
      Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum aaa
      Lorem Ipsum"><button>btn</button></td>
        <td class=" tooltip" data-title="Lorem Ipsum
      Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum aaa
      Lorem Ipsum"><button>btn</button></td>
        <td class=" tooltip" data-title="Lorem Ipsum
      Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum aaa
      Lorem Ipsum"><button>btn</button></td>
    </table>
</div>
```